# Zxing using external camera

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zxing

I want to integrate my external camera that I connect to tablet with my application using zxing. I know it is possible to use front camera but i would like to connect it via external. Is it possible? if yes how can i do it. I tested my external camera on my Nexus 7 and it does work but i had to use special app and set chmod for device. If exists faster way to set it up without using terminal all the time but only using library in my application i will be glad.

Another iteresting thing is that if I will be able to use my front camera in Nexus 7 to scan any bar codes because it has bad quality.

I also would like to know if exists some other worth testing library for android to use external or front camera.

Comment: Hi, @Tr0k any updates on this issue?